# how to show google recaptcha error message with javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

After validation, if captcha is not selected, a response is returned with g-recaptcha-response.

Because there is a dash in g-recaptcha-response, I can not display it

```js
if (response.data.msg.g-recaptcha-response) {
document.getElementById('captcha').innerText = response.data.msg.g-recaptcha-response
}
```

Comment: Try alert. Alerting the captcha error is recommended.

Comment: You should use square bracket notation to access properties with dashes. Would look something like this: `response.data.msg["g-recaptcha-response"]`

Answer (score 1):

Create a span or div tag where you want to display the message. Here I have just put it under the captcha box.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha">
</div>
<span id="error-captcha"></span>
```

Then validate with the script below and append the validation message to it:

```
if(grecaptcha.getResponse().length == 0){
     $('#error-captcha').empty()
     $('#error-captcha').append("Please tick the recaptcha.");
    }
```